# Connecting to bigquery with spark on local

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to a run a code to read from bigquery do some transformation using spark. Getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error accessing: bucket: test-n, object: spark/output/wordcount
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.wrapException(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1707)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getObject(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1733)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getItemInfo(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1618)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.ForwardingGoogleCloudStorage.getItemInfo(ForwardingGoogleCloudStorage.java:214)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getFileInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1094)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getFileStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1422)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
at com.spark.bigquery.App.main(App.java:67)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Robot is missing a project number."
}
```

I have done the configuration of service account and email in the code. Placed the P12 file also.

```
conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", projectId);
        // Use service account for authentication. The service account key file is located at the path
        // specified by the configuration property google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile.
        conf.set(EntriesCredentialConfiguration.BASE_KEY_PREFIX +
                EntriesCredentialConfiguration.ENABLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNTS_SUFFIX,
                "true");

        conf.set(EntriesCredentialConfiguration.BASE_KEY_PREFIX +
                EntriesCredentialConfiguration.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEYFILE_SUFFIX,
                "aesthetic-genre-216711-3a23f8112565.p12");

        conf.set(EntriesCredentialConfiguration.BASE_KEY_PREFIX +
                EntriesCredentialConfiguration.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUFFIX,
                "reddevil.c06@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Hello Siddharth. I'm looking to achieve something similar, did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yeah got it working, In the emal section above of the conf it has to be the service account whose key we have given that email.

Comment: Superb, thank you for the info 

Comment: Hello again Siddharth. What did you mean when you said "Placed the P12 file also." I'm clueless as to what that means and if its something I need to do.

Comment: I've got a similar query here if someone/anyone wouldn't mind taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190969/bigquery-connector-for-spark-on-dataproc-cannot-authenticate-using-service-acc

Comment: @Jamiet Yes you need to generate the service account key file in the P12 format because the spark-bigquery connector uses P12 format (it was atleast when i used it) And you have to keep it at the path and give its location. I was using a maven project so i kept it in src/main/resources and thats why just gave the name of the file as it is in classpath.

Let me know if you need other help.

Comment: Siddharth, really appreciate you taking the time to reply, thank you. You're absolutely right of course and I've also since figured out that I *can* use the .json format by specifying `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile` instead of `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile`

Comment: yeah acutally i used json but was getting error so rolled backed to P12..

Comment: I can see that the problem was solved. Could you post a concrete answer? so that it helps others and it can be up voted. Thanks.