# BigQuery connector for Spark on Dataproc - cannot authenticate using service account key file

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I have followed [Use the BigQuery connector with Spark](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example) to successfully get data from a publicly available dataset. I now need to access a bigquery dataset that is owned by one of our clients and for which I have been given a  service account key file (I know that the service account key file is valid because I can use it to connect using the [Google BigQuery library for Python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)).

I have followed what Igor Dvorzhak recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120480/201657)

> To use service account key file authorization you need to set `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable` property to true and point BigQuery connector to a service account json keyfile using `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile` property

like so:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSessionBQExample").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

bucket = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
project = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory =     'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input{}'.format(bucket, datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))

project_id = 'clientproject'#'publicdata'
dataset_id = 'clientdataset'#samples'
table_id = 'clienttable'#'shakespeare'
conf = {
    # Input Parameters.
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': project_id,
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': dataset_id,
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': table_id,
    'mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable': 'true'
}

# Load data in from BigQuery.
table_data = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)

print ('row tally={}'.format(table_data.toDF().count()))
```

I have placed the service account key file at `/tmp/keyfile.json` on the master node and all the worker nodes of the cluster then I submit my job like so:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
    ./bq_pyspark.py  \
    --cluster $CLUSTER \
    --region $REGION \
    --properties=spark.hadoop.mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/tmp/keyfile.json
```

I have also tried:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
    ./bq_pyspark.py  \
    --cluster $CLUSTER \
    --region $REGION \
    --properties=spark.hadoop.mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/tmp/keyfile.json,spark.hadoop.mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable=true
```

Here are the pertinent sections of the job output:

> Bigquery connector version 0.10.7-hadoop2
>   18/11/07 13:36:47 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory: Creating BigQuery from default credential.
>   18/11/07 13:36:47 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory: Creating BigQuery from given credential.
>   18/11/07 13:36:47 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryConfiguration: Using working path: 'gs://dataproc-9e5dc592-1a35-42e6-9dd6-5f9dd9c8df87-europe-west1/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input20181107133646'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/tmp/b6973a26c76d4069a86806dfbd2d7d0f/bq_pyspark.py", line 30, in 
>       conf=conf)
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 702, in newAPIHadoopRDD
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in **call**
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
>   : com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
>   {
>     "code" : 403,
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Access Denied: Table clientproject:clientdatatset.clienttable: The user mydataprocserviceaccount@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table clientproject:clientdatatset.clienttable.",
>       "reason" : "accessDenied"
>     } ],
>     "message" : "Access Denied: Table clientproject:clientdatatset.clienttable: The user mydataprocserviceaccount@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table clientproject:clientdatatset.clienttable."
>   }

The line

> 18/11/07 13:36:47 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory: Creating BigQuery from default credential.

possibly suggests that I'm not passing the credentials from the service account key file correctly so I guess I've misunderstood what Igor said (or some info is missing).

If anyone can let me know where I'm going wrong I'd very much appreciate it.

UPDATE...
I have attempted to supply the required auth configuration via code instead of via the command-line:

```
conf = {
    # Input Parameters.
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': project_id,
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': dataset_id,
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': table_id,
    'mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable': 'true',
    'mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile': '/tmp/keyfile.json',
    'mapred.bq.auth.service.account.email': 'username@clientproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
}
```

This time I got a different error:

> 18/11/07 16:44:21 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory: Creating BigQuery from default credential.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/tmp/cb5cbb16d59945dd926cab2c1f2f5524/bq_pyspark.py", line 39, in 
>       conf=conf)
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 702, in newAPIHadoopRDD
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in **call**
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
>     File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
>   : java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123
>           at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:881)
>           at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1939)
>           at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:82)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:115)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:670)
>           at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromPrivateKeyServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:251)
>           at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialConfiguration.getCredential(CredentialConfiguration.java:100)
>           at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory.createBigQueryCredential(BigQueryFactory.java:95)
>           at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory.getBigQuery(BigQueryFactory.java:115)
>           at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory.getBigQueryHelper(BigQueryFactory.java:103)

I googled "toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123" which led me to [toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312902/toderinputstream-rejects-tag-type-123) which suggests I need to authenticate using a P12 file. This is consistent with the mention of `sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore` in the call stack. Hence, I think I need a P12 file (aka a PKCS#12 format file) rather than a .json file which means I need to go back to the client to ask for that - and from experience I think it may take some time to get the P12 file. I'll report back if/when i get anywhere.

UPDATE 2... figured it out, with Igor's help. I was wrongly specifying `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile`, it needed to be `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile`. Thus the pertinent section of code becomes:

```
conf = {
    # Input Parameters.
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': project_id,
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': dataset_id,
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': table_id,
    'mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable': 'true',
    'mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile': '/tmp/keyfile.json'
}
table_data = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)
```

and the submit command is simply

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
    ./bq_pyspark.py  \
    --cluster $CLUSTER \
    --region $REGION
```

It now works, I am able to access data in biquery from spark-on-dataproc, authenticating using a service account json key file. Thank you Igor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be here:

> Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/tmp/keyfile.json

To fix this, you [should](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) set Hadoop properties with `spark.hadoop` prefix in Spark:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark ./bq_pyspark.py \
  --cluster $CLUSTER --region $REGION \
  --properties=spark.hadoop.mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/tmp/keyfile.json
```

Comment: thx Igor, I changed to use `--properties=spark.hadoop.mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/tmp/keyfile.json` and it did get rid of that warning however its still not working, I get the same error. I have updated the post above accordingly.

Comment: Igor, have updated the post with more info, I think i need a PKCS12 format file. Watch this space.

Comment: Do you have a service account key file in P12 or JSON format? If it's in P12 format then you should use [`mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/ac83bd8a9d2bd4f44b003f45e4bf67f0e14edcdc/gcs/conf/gcs-core-default.xml#L142) property to set path to it.

On a side note, I would recommend to use newer Dataproc version, latest pre-1.3 images should have BQ connector `0.10.11` installed, not `0.10.7`.

Comment: Looks like you made a mistake in your code configuration. You set json key file path for `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile` property instead of `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile` property.

Comment: Igor, you are absolutely right, thank you. `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile` instead of `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile` did the trick. Thank you very very much.